# Do DFSR replication group act independantly?

Tags: dfs-r

I can't seem to find the answer to this.

I have 2 replication groups for 2 very different sets of data. We recently had a problem that will cause us to restore about 50GB of data on the 1st group. We have the first group set to throttle data during business hours.

If I put the large amount of data in, will that stop the 2 group from replicating or do they replicate asynchronously?